# Analytical solution for linear second order PDE with two space variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, linear-pde

I appreciate if anyone can help me with the solution of below PDE $u(x,y)$
$$u_{xx}(ax+b)+u_x(cx+d)+u_y(ey)+u(f\frac{y^2}{x}+gx)=h(x,y)$$
where a,b,c,d,e,f,g are constants and h is a function of exponential of x and y. I reached to this problem as a midpoint for the solution of a bigger problem. My first guess was the separation of variables but $u(f\frac{y^2}{x}+gx)$ was my problem. Now, I am thinking about using the method of characteristics. Please let me know if you need further information. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: What's the domain and BC?

Comment: Also, (more importantly) the function $u$ is a function of only one variable so what's the meaning of the partial derivatives?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. u is a function of x and y and the PDE include first and second derivative wrt x and first derivative wrt y (third term in LHS). For x, the boundary is zero at infinite and du/dx=0 at the origin. x domain is 0 to infinite and y is -pi to pi (it is in polar coordinate). The function is even wrt y.